# How to filter NA values of group of columns in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have created a datatable with 3 different group of observations as,

```
DT_EX= dt.Frame({
    'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c'],
    'id':[3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
    'shop':['dmart','dmart','dmart','dmart','amzn','amzn','amzn','amzn'],
    'beef':[23,None,None,None,93,None,None,None],
    'eggs':[None,33,None,None,None,103,None,None],
    'fork':[None,None,10,None,None,None,210,None],
    'veg':[None,None,None,40,None,None,None,340]
})
```

It's output as,

```
   | country  id  shop   beef  eggs  fork  veg
-- + -------  --  -----  ----  ----  ----  ---
 0 | a         3  dmart    23    NA    NA   NA
 1 | a         3  dmart    NA    33    NA   NA
 2 | a         3  dmart    NA    NA    10   NA
 3 | a         3  dmart    NA    NA    NA   40
 4 | b         4  amzn     93    NA    NA   NA
 5 | b         4  amzn     NA   103    NA   NA
 6 | c         4  amzn     NA    NA   210   NA
 7 | c         4  amzn     NA    NA    NA  340

[8 rows x 7 columns]
```

Now i have applied a recommended grouping on first 3 fields of datatable, aggregated(sum) of other remaining columns(beef,eggs,fork,veg) as

```
In [5]: DT_EX[:,first(f[:3]).extend(sum(f[3:])),by(f[:3])]
```

It's output as-

```
Out[5]: 
   | country  id  shop   country.0  id.0  shop.0  beef  eggs  fork  veg
-- + -------  --  -----  ---------  ----  ------  ----  ----  ----  ---
 0 | a         3  dmart  a             3  dmart     23    33    10   40
 1 | b         4  amzn   b             4  amzn      93   103     0    0
 2 | c         4  amzn   c             4  amzn       0     0   210  340

[3 rows x 10 columns]
```

Here it gives a correct output, but it's adding duplicate columns, and another observation is that its filling NA values with 0, it can be found on C observation.

Here i did some workaround as

```
In [7]: DT_EX[:,first(f[:3]).extend(sum(f[3:])),by(f[:3])][:,f[:].remove(f[3:6])]
```

and its output as,

```
Out[7]: 
   | country  id  shop   beef  eggs  fork  veg
-- + -------  --  -----  ----  ----  ----  ---
 0 | a         3  dmart    23    33    10   40
 1 | b         4  amzn     93   103     0    0
 2 | c         4  amzn      0     0   210  340
```

But i think it's not a feasible solution as i always have to specify which columns to be hidden in .remove function,

Would you have any other ideas/suggestions on it ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
DT_EX[:, dt.sum(f[:].remove(f[:3])), by(f[:3])]
```

However it still feels kind of awkward. I would expect to just use `dt.sum(f[:])` and have the columns in `by` removed automatically. Not sure if there's a different syntax.

**Edit**:

As Pasha pointed out in the comments, in this case it is simpler to use:

```
DT_E[:, dt.sum(f[3:]), by=f([:3])]
```

Comment: i think this is just right. hopefully the API gets beter

Comment: Yup, got it worked for now. however it should improve as it will just keep NA's as it is rather than filling in with 0. any how i would go with it for now. i'm just trying to implement functions on reshaping datatables, in this process i have been learning a lot of pydatatable.. thanks for your help on it.

Comment: or simply `dt.sum(f[3:])`

Comment: You are correct that `f[:]` should have removed the by- columns automatically; I filed issue #2460 on datatable's GitHub to correct this.

Comment: Thanks, @Pasha! I was about to ask you if this was the expected behavior. Going to give that issue a thumbs up.